# WordPress>EditMedia>ThumbnailCrop>broken?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, crop

I'm learning to make WordPress themes and am testing using the TwentyTwelve theme as reference to ensure my theme is compatible etc, all good. The following issue happens while using a fresh WP install with TwentyTwelve and no plugins:

Automatically generated thumbnails work well and make 150px squares for category views, but sometimes an image doesn't look right with centre weighted crop; and thus needs adjusted in the Edit Media section. If I re-crop and make a new thumbnail from the Edit Media page it all appears to work within WP Admin, but the public site breaks down and shows a rescaled version of the full-size image; not my newly created 150px thumbnail.

In my own theme I've added a php function to remove the 'e1358606444772' stuff added to the thumbnail filename, so the new thumbnail now replaces the automatically created one with the correct filename and path, but still I get the same response: thumbnails show at the correct width; but are actually rescaled full-size images at the original aspect ratio.

I've posted on the WP forums and can't get a reply. Anybody shed any light on this please?
Thanks ....